# SBT Create a DockerFile Using a Function

Tags: scala, sbt

I was trying this piece of code:

```
// Get the Docker Configurations
def dockerConfForModule(moduleName: String): Dockerfile = {
  val jarFile: File = (Compile / packageBin / sbt.Keys.`package`).value
  val classpath = (Compile / managedClasspath).value
  val mainclass = (Compile / packageBin / mainClass).value.getOrElse(sys.error("Expected exactly one main class"))
  val jarTarget = s"/app/${jarFile.getName}"
  // Make a colon separated classpath with the JAR file
  val classpathString = classpath.files.map("/app/" + _.getName)
    .mkString(":") + ":" + jarTarget
  new Dockerfile {
    // Base image
    from("openjdk:8-jre")
    // Add all files on the classpath
    add(classpath.files, "/app/")
    // Add the JAR file
    add(jarFile, jarTarget)
    // On launch run Java with the classpath and the main class
    entryPoint("java", "-cp", classpathString, mainclass)
  }
}
```

Which I'm calling as a function in one of my module like below:

```
// Define Sub Modules and its settings
lazy val cleanse = (project in file(MODULE_NAME_CLEANSE)).dependsOn(core)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    enablingCoverageSettings,
    name := MODULE_NAME_CLEANSE,
    description := "Clean the incoming data for training purposes",
    docker / dockerfile := dockerConfForModule(MODULE_NAME_CLEANSE)
  )
  .enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
```

But this runs into an error:

```
/home/joesan/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation/build.sbt:22: error: `value` can only be called on a task within a task definition macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, or Def.task.
  val jarFile: File = (Compile / packageBin / sbt.Keys.`package`).value
                                                                  ^
/home/joesan/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation/build.sbt:23: error: `value` can only be called on a task within a task definition macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, or Def.task.
  val classpath = (Compile / managedClasspath).value
                                               ^
/home/joesan/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation/build.sbt:24: error: `value` can only be called on a task within a task definition macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, or Def.task.
  val mainclass = (Compile / packageBin / mainClass).value.getOrElse(sys.error("Expected exactly one main class"))
                                                     ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

What is wrong in what I'm trying?

Comment: The error says it all, you need to use special constructs to be able to use these `(...).value`. The easy workaround is to get these values as input parameter of your method.